# Deserialize SQL query result into dynamic object c#

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic

I have an SQL query which return a result with column name always different and I'd like to map the result into a C# array of objects.

Usually, when I have columns name static I create a class with members name matching columns name and it works, but in this case, columns name are always different in name and number, because I'm using PIVOT operator inside the query.

How can I map the query result into array of objects since I don't know the columns number and the columns name?

Comment: What API are you using to query the database? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing query then create a query with existing output in SQL and set aliases for every column.